# How to get the id of the wrapping element onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the ID of the wrapping element onclick. Something like this

```
<p id="wrapper"> Hello <span id="one"> how </span> are <span id="two">you</span></p>
```

So here is the requirement:

When  click `how` i want to get the id of the wrapping `span` & that is `one` and when click `are` it should show wrapping `<p>` id and so on for `you` also.

I am using jquery for this & i trid with `.prop`, `.wrap` but every time i am getting the ID of the outer `<p>` element.

So please suggest how can i do this?

If it is a duplicate one so please provide me the link.

Thanks

Comment: (Not a downvoter) Probably because the element you want is contained in the click event and is pretty basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look inside the event argument passed into the click function

```
$('#wrapper').click(function(e){
   console.log(e.target.id); 
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hkW28/)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple jQuery.

```
$('span').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zjysy/

Comment: This wont work for "are".

Comment: I realised that after I posted. However, wirey's answer does it much better than what I would have come up with. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could easily attach the Listener to the spans:

```
var forEach = Function.call.bind([].forEach);
spans=document.querySelectorAll("p span");
forEach(spans, function(span){
    span.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        alert(e.target.id);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMWqq/

Comment: Since you're going ES5, you could do `var forEach = Function.call.bind([].forEach);` And then `forEach(spans, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
$('#wrapper').click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).closest('[id]').prop('id'));
});
```

**Update:** Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/zjysy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/E6NFG/

```
$('p, span').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
alert(e.target.id);
});
```

Comment: Please consider qualifying this answer with some commentary and explanation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span, p').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        return false;
    });
});
```